# Fliter by user entity reference view not working

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have An Entity referenced view for users to call it on a auto complete field.it working fine only for role administors not for other roles.when i given permission 'Administer Users' to other roles it start working.but i dont want to give permission to that role.how to access user data in that view by a user?

i have tried this.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'node_inbox_form'){
  $match_operator = $form['field_to']['widget']['target_id']['#selection_settings']['match_operator'];
  $form['field_to']['widget']['target_id']['#selection_handler'] = 'views';
  $form['field_to']['widget']['target_id']['#selection_settings'] = [
    'view' => [
      'view_name' => 'user_list_reference',
      'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
      'arguments' => [],
    ],
    'match_operator' => $match_operator,
  ];
}
}
```